# When i am clicking left side menu need to scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i am clicking left side menu  need to right side page scroll going up. Please help.

[image]

Comment: what exactly is your question? :D

Answer (score 2):

to let content scroll to a specified position, you can use the jquery function `.scrollTop()`

visit for documentation https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp

maybe this will help you:

```
$(".your_button").click(function(){
    $(".your_content_container").scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ScrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$(YourLeftSideMenuID).click(function(){
    $(YourRightSideComponent).scrollTop(0);
});
```